# How to find these master records whose totals are not accurate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables (master-details relationship). The master table has a column (called total) recording the number of details records for the same master record. Having this column is for the performance reason). Here are the table specs:

```
table: MySum
column: id
column: total (total of MyDetail records for the same MySum record)

table: MyDetail
column: name
column: MySum
```

Because deletion of details records, the total in the master table may not be correct and so I would like to find these master records whose totals are not accurate. Here is the SQL I have. However, it generates zero records and I know this is not right based on the actual data.

```
select s.id, s.total from MySum s where s.total <> (select count(*) from MyDetail d where s.id = d.MySum group by d.MySum)
```

What is the right SQL statement?

I am using MS SQL Server and database-specific statement is okay for me. However, generic statement would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do the calculation in the `where`, you can.  You just need only the correlated subquery rather than a `group by`:

```
select s.id, s.total
from MySum s
where s.total <> (select count(*)
                  from MyDetail d
                  where s.id = d.MySum
                 );
```

EDIT:

If you want the count, then use a `join` and `group by`:

```
select s.id, s.total, d_cnt
from MySum s left join
     (select d.MySum, count(*) as d_cnt
      from MyDetail d
      group by d.MySum
     ) d
     on s.id = d.MySum
where s.total <> d_cnt or not (s.total = 0 and d_cnt is null);
```

Comment: it must be count(*). The OP's table design is: _(total of MyDetail records for the same MySum record)_

Comment: Gordon, thanks for your input. I tested your code, and it does not produce the correct results.

Comment: Gordon, I got it working. Here is the final statement. Use count(d.mysum) instead of sum(d.mysum). Could you please update your answer so that I can select it? Besides, How can I return count(d.mysum) in the statement too ?

Comment: Gordon, count(*) is not working. Only count(d.mysum) works.

Comment: @curious1 . . . They should be exactly the same, because `d.MySum` cannot be `NULL`.

Comment: You are right. Do you happen to know how to return the total count(*) in the statement too?